# Jitsi crashes sound every time

Tags: opensuse, audio, java

No matter which version of the software I download and install from [jitsi.org](https://jitsi.org/), running **Jitsi** causes the sound on my OpenSUSE 12.3 machine to be replaced by a low hissing noise. This persists even if I exit Jitsi, and I've not been able to find a way to restart the sound system. A reboot is the only way to restore sound.

My soundcard is a Creative SoundBlaster Audigy 2 Platinum, and sound works fine in other applications.

This happens whether I run Jitsi after installing from a Linux package, or run from source using `make`. As soon as Jitsi starts loading, the sound dies and is replaced with hissing. I have tried Jitsi versions from the "stable" and "nightly build" areas of the Jitsi download page. (Currently, versions 2.2-latest, 2.2-4603, and 2.3-4712.)

Any ideas what I can try in order to successfully run Jitsi with sound in OpenSUSE?

Comment: Versions and audio hardware would help.

Comment: Updated with sound hardware and Jitsi version.